# I'm trying to get the internet connection status in Android but I can't get it right

Tags: android

I've seen some solutions in here regarding the issue, but when I try in the Android emulator when internet is disabled, my application crashes.
Here's the code that I tried:

```
 cm= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null)connect=true;
    if(connect){

            new AsyncTask<URL,Integer, Long>() {
                @Override
                protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                    try {
                        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com "); 
                        if (ipAddr.equals(""))connect=false;
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }
```

So the boolean variable 'connect' should be false when Internet is disabled in my laptop, but it is always true.
This code is in my onResume method by the way

Comment: are you executing the async task?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to change a final variable `connect`. When you use a variable inside an anonymous class, it automatically becomes final and therefore you can't change it. You should return a `boolean` from your task and assign it to `connect` instead.

```
AsyncTask mTask = new AsyncTask<URL,Integer, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
                    InetAddress ipAddr = new String();
                    try {
                        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.google.com "); 

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                return ipAddr.equals("");
            }
}
```

and then get the result:

```
mTask.execute();
connect = mTask.get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read a few books on Java and this is the first time I'm reading about this rule. How did you know about it?

Comment: I just tried it and I now get the error " An error occurred while executing doInBackground()"

Comment: what is the stacktrace?